# How to take a screenshot of an embedded scrollable section on a website?

Tags: screenshot

If you head on over to Walmart's store search section and type in your zip code, you will get a list of 20 stores along with a map next to it. I would like to take a screenshot of the map AND the list in its entirety. I don't mind doing two steps: 1) the map, and 2) the list.

However, I can't figure out at all how to get a screenshot of that long list. As you can see, only a small portion of the list is visible. Also, it doesn't have to be a screenshot. I would be satisfied with copying and pasting, but the structure of the list gets destroyed when I do that. The items on the right side of the list (Pickup Options and At this store), end up going to the bottom rather than to the right as they are.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a full page screen shot, since the part that interests the poster is hidden

My solution requires some fidgeting but works.

I'll explain it using Firefox, but similar operations can be accomplished with modern browsers which all have now a built-in html/css inspector.

- right click just inside the scrollable list, very near the top left corner, select "Inspect element": a windows pops up with HTML code on the left, and CSS on the right
- on the HTML code display, find an entry saying `<div id="resultStores" style="height:311px;"></div>`. Edit that entry, replacing the figure between `height:` and `px;` with the word `auto`

=> `<div id="resultStores" style="height:auto;"></div>`

- look above that entry, you'll find an other div, `<div id="searchInfo">`
- notice on the CSS panel on the right a block titled `#searchinfo` with `overflow: hidden` in it. Replace the word `hidden` with the word `visible`

Tada, your page should now display the full list

Get familiar with the process, and now it's time to install a full page screenshot utility. With Firefox, I recommend the [Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/fireshot/) plugin.

- set height of `<div id="resultStores">` to `auto`
- set overflow of `<div id="searchInfo">` to `visible`
- with the same inspector tool, you can also remove the two blocks on the footer, that will come in the way and spoil a part of the screenshot: right click to inspect those elements, right click again to remove the node, repeat.
- right click on the page, and use FireShot to capture the full page.

Et voilà :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is still a small problem. The ads on the bottom show through the list. In other words, the list is transparent. P.S. I was trying to do what you suggested here, but I only changed the 311 px, and didn't know about the 2nd portion nor would I have figured it out.

Comment: As I said, use the inspector to remove the ads and footer. Oh, and if you use Firefox or Chrome, you can choose to get rids of ads altogether using AdBlockPlus. :)

Comment: I did this with Firebug in Firefox. I don't understand how it works with the Firefox Inspector. i.e. I search for 311px and nothing comes up. Also, does the Walmart page really have no /body and /html or are they included in one of the js scripts?

Comment: I routinely use FireBug too, but since you did not say anything about the browser you're using or your proficiency in this area, I went for simple and standard. If you "inspect" right inside the top left corner (using the builtin FF inspector), the height:311px should appear immediately. As for the walmart page, it indeed appears that the coder chose to go lazy and omit to close the html and body tags, guessing that the browser will cope with that gracefully. Not very clean coding imho.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is called a "full page screenshot". As you haven't said what browser you're using, it's difficult to recommend an application, but here are some examples:

http://www.designer-daily.com/5-ways-to-capture-full-webpage-screenshots-15291
http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Comment: I only want a portion of the full page. One of the programs mentioned on the page you directed me to is Fireshot, which I already have. There is no way to take a screenshot of just the embedded scrollable portion.

Comment: You could screenshot the entire viewport, then crop down to the portion that you actually need?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are understanding the problem. For the portion I need, only a part of it is visible. I have to scroll to see the rest (and I don't mean scroll the entire webpage, but rather an embedded portion).

Answer (score 0):

Fast-forward to 2019, and this is still a problem. My use case is saving the Game Log from dominion.games, which is, just like OP's use case, an embedded scrollable section of the website, and I want to screenshot the whole thing, not just the visible part.

I was able to solve it using Sxilderik's answer with some adjustments that were significant enough I decided to post them as a new answer here.  I'm using Firefox version 69, which has some very helpful screenshotting tools built in. I had to adjust the page as follows:

1. Tools -> Web Developer -> Inspector
2. Scroll through the HTML in the Inspector to find the element I want to screenshot. As I mouseover any HTML node in the Inspector, Firefox highlights that element on the page, so it's not too hard to find the element I want.
3. Right-click the HTML node's "style" attribute in the Inspector -> Attributes -> Edit Attribute "style"
4. Type in `style="height:auto; z-index:100; background:black;"` (enter)
5. Right-click the HTML node in the Inspector -> Screenshot Node
6. Tools -> Downloads -> (find the new screenshot) -> (double-click to see the result in a new tab)

Step 4 may need to be tweaked depending on the website you're doing this on. Obviously, the background color `black` may need to be different on different websites.  Less obviously, a high value of `z-index` can bring the desired element in front of other overlapping elements, so I didn't need any of the other tools or adjustments mentioned in Sxilderik's answer and comments.